# Is it possible to use bpy.props.PointerProperty to store a pointer to an object?

Tags: python, properties

If the user renames an object, the reference via string key is lost.

Is it possible to store a pointer to an object in a [property assigned](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.PointerProperty) to a class of `bpy.types`

I checked

```
>>> type(obj.bl_rna.properties['parent'])
<class 'bpy.types.PointerProperty'>
```

However `type` for `PointerProperty` is expected to be a subclass of `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` but `bpy.types.Object` is inherited from `bpy_struct` and `bpy.types.ID`.

Comment: Duplicate -------- Finally found it here [assign-datablock-to-custom-property](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/assign-datablock-to-custom-property). It is not possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>No, despite the sound of `PointerProperty`, its purpose is not to store a pointer/reference to an ID datablock</strike>. **Update:** you can use it to reference ID datablocks in Blender 2.79 and above, see the [other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98651/1363).

It's used to organize a set of properties in a nice way, especially if your addon registers a lot of properties:

```
# Bad, clutters scene objects and may even conflict with other addons
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop_1 = bpy.props.IntProperty()
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop_2 = bpy.props.IntProperty()
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop_3 = bpy.props.IntProperty()

# Good, organize properties as a group
class MyAddonProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_prop_1 = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    my_prop_2 = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    my_prop_3 = bpy.props.IntProperty()

bpy.types.Scene.my_addon = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyAddonProperties)

# Access it e.g. like
#bpy.context.scene.my_addon.my_prop_1
```

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.props.html#propertygroup-example

What you are looking for is `bpy.props.IDProperty`, but we don't have that (shame!)

These kind of properties need to be created in C, like `Object.parent`.

In Python, you can only store by name (`StringProperty`). Use it together with a `CollectionProperty` and [layout.prop_search()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_search).

Note: The `StringProperty` isn't tied to the object's name. It's possible to abuse app handlers to check for name changes and to update the property accordingly, but I wouldn't consider it very safe nor efficient.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/object-selection-box-in-addon has an example of doing this with StringProperty.

Comment: So in a nutshell: use PropertyGroup / PointerProperty for custom properties attached to bpy._types_ and use CollectionProperty to add custom properties to _objects_. Thanks CoDEmanX, that clarified things for me!

Answer (score 19):

As of [release 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/PythonAPI)
it is possible to [store a pointer to an object](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointer#bpy.props.PointerProperty)

Usage example:

```
my_pointer = PointerProperty(name="My Pointer", type=bpy.types.Object)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add pointer property to store a object, and scenes, textures and all other data types in 2.79 version

```
bpy.types.Scene.MyPointer = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name = "my pointer", description = "my descr",
type=bpy.types.Texture) #add a texture pointer
```

or

```
bpy.types.Scene.MyPointer = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name = "my pointer", description = "my descr",
type=bpy.types.Mesh) #add a mesh pointer
```

Comment: _"We can add pointer property to store ... all other data types in 2.79 version"_ <-- **This is very incorrect.** Only types which subclass `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` or `bpy.types.ID` can be referenced by a PointerProperty. You **cannot** use a PointerProperty to point to any other type! Notably, this means `bpy_struct` and all of its descendents **cannot** be referenced by a PointerProperty. Not everything inherits from `ID`; in fact, many notable "data block" types actually inherit from `bpy_struct`. For example, `PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.ShapeKey)` is invalid and will always fail.