# Object selection box in addon

Tags: python, add-on

In my addon panel, how can I have an object selection box?  And what data type would I use to store the the selected object?

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Building off of the answer by @CoDEmanX, here's a simple example:

```
import bpy    

class OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene               
        layout.prop_search(scene, "theChosenObject", scene, "objects")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.theChosenObject = bpy.props.StringProperty()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Object.theChosenObject


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

which gives:

[image]

## How script works

The [`prop_search`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_search) command lets the user choose one item from a bpy "collection" (in this case, the collection `context.scene.objects`) and saves the name of that item into a string (the string `context.scene.theChosenObject`).

If you need to use the object in a different part of script.  Use

```
scene = context.scene
obj = scene.objects[scene.theChosenObject]
```

By the way, if you had wanted a "Materials Selection Box", you could have used

```
layout.prop_search(scene, "theChosenMaterial", bpy.data, "materials")
```

and similarly for textures, meshes, or any other bpy collection.

## Limitations

We are only saving the name of the object (for example, `scene.theChosenObject` could be `'Cube'`).  If the user changes the name of the object, `scene.theChosenObject` will not change and you will not be able to use it to reference the object anymore.

See here for [more](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/is-it-possible-to-use-bpy-props-pointerproperty-to-store-a-pointer-to-an-object) on this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the second code box say `scene.object[scene.theChosenObject]` rather than `scene.object(scene.theChosenObject)`?

Comment: I think `unregister` should `del` property from the `Scene`, not from the `Object`? i.e `del bpy.types.Scene.theChosenObject`

Answer (score 10):

Use [prop_search()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_search), a `StringProperty` and a `CollectionProperty`.

```
import bpy

enum_items = (
    ('FOO', 'Foo', ''),
    ('BAR', 'Bar', '')
)

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        col = layout.column()        
        col.prop_search(context.scene, "coll_string", context.scene, "coll", icon='OBJECT_DATA')

def populate_coll(scene):
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(populate_coll)
    scene.coll.clear()
    for identifier, name, description in enum_items:
        scene.coll.add().name = name

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    bpy.types.Scene.coll = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(
        type=bpy.types.PropertyGroup
    )

    bpy.types.Scene.coll_string = bpy.props.StringProperty()

    # Hack for testing
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(populate_coll)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.coll
    del bpy.types.Scene.coll_string


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

For limitations please read:
[Is it possible to use bpy.props.PointerProperty to store a pointer to an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/is-it-possible-to-use-bpy-props-pointerproperty-to-store-a-pointer-to-an-object)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an updated answer built on previously accepted answer.
Since 2.79, you can use `bpy.props.PointerProperty` to store references to blender data blocks.

You can then use `prop` instead of `prop_search` for selection box. `prop_search` is still useful if you want to select from a specific collection.

This solves the problem of modifying the object ( for example if you rename the object, the property will be updated). Also, deleting the object will not delete its data as, long as it is referenced somewhere. After all its references are removed, it gets deleted on file reload.

```
import bpy    

class OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout            
        layout.prop(context.scene, "theChosenObject")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.theChosenObject = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Object.theChosenObject


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Can poll to narrow down selection see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101303/15543