# Object selection box with eyedropper

Tags: python, interface, add-on

How to add an eyedropper functionality to `prop_search` in my addon?

```
col.prop_search(scene, "string_property", context.scene, "objects")
```

This code will create `prop_search` just like on the animation below, but without an eyedropper.

[image: eyedropper]

Comment: I think the property should be a pointer and the eyedropper will appear

Comment: I already tried `PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)`, but it seems that pointer property points only to classes, and cannot store an ID block.

Comment: did you find something yet ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spoke to [Campbell Barton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42) (the developer who got eyedropper functionality implemented) about this, he said that this kind of functionality is not available in Python API at the moment.

**UPDATE:**

Blender 2.79 now allows to create add-on properties which reference datablocks.

```
custom_property: PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
```

Using this property with a `prop_search()` we'll get search box with an eyedropper.

**UPDATE 2:**

Usage of `prop_search()` is not necessary, in this case `prop()` will do just fine.
*Noted by [J. Bakker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/50862/j-bakker).*

Comment: Did you submit a feature request in the Blender bug tracker?

Comment: I added a feature request to the Blender tracker: https://developer.blender.org/T48357

Comment: The same feature request at the new community website for Blender development ideas: https://rightclickselect.com/p/scripting/zkbbbc/

Comment: @brockmann, [example code](https://hastebin.com/cememubuja.py)

Comment: Even without a `prop_search`, just a regular `prop`, you will get a Eyedropper

Comment: I'll have to try this out! Is it possible to capture the object you picked, and update a UIList item with that object/data? Mainly just need to see if / how can trigger a def or something if possible, on picked?

Comment: @mattli911 yes `PonterProperty` has `update` parameter [API doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.PointerProperty).

Comment: @MikhailRachinskiy your example code is no longer there. Can you explain how to use this again? Thanks

Comment: @JosephBrandenburg It still there, property implementation example is under first `UPDATE`, and property UI usage is under second `UPDATE 2`.

Comment: When I click the link I get an empty page. But I figured out what I was doing wrong: it isn't supported for bpy.types.Operator classes.

Answer (score 4):

**A working example based on answers given.**

[image]

Given the struggles of [How to draw Object selection with eyedropper layout using Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159041/how-to-draw-object-selection-with-eyedropper-layout-using-python-script)  here is an edit to the script from that question

Puts a panel in the "scene" tab of the properties area.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Prop Panels"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop_search(scene, "prop", context.scene, "objects")
        #or 
        col.prop(scene, "prop")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.prop = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101303/15543 re creating a poll method for the pointer to filter, for example, for objects of type armature in the scene.