# How to invoke the mirror modifier object eyedropper command with python?

Tags: python, mirror

I'm creating a simple script where once executed it adds a mirror modifier to an object. The next step would be to invoke this button through the script and then I click on the object I want to mirror my selected object around:

[image]

But the command doesn't show up on the last executed command list and I can't find anything about it on the net. I just want to execute the command this button invokes.

my code:

```
import bpy from bpy.types import Menu 

class MirrorPicker(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mirror.picker" 
    bl_label = "Mirror Picker" 

    def execute(self, context): 
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR') 
        # the eyedropper code goes here somewhere
        return {'FINISHED'} 

def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_class(MirrorPicker) 

def unregister(): 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MirrorPicker) 

if __name__ == "__main__": register()
```

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper, but if you could make a similar operator that picks up the `active object` like in [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes).

Comment: so, the 1st link says that it can't be done with python. and where do i look for it in the animation nodes link you provided. if implementing manually means some uber level coding then i'm out of luck as i just do basic scripting to streamline my modeling workflow :)

Comment: then we can mark it as duplicate, because the answer is still the same.

Comment: Stumbled upon this (due to a link from zeffii) https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow/tree/63228e8ea25abc48388d83c534fbdc07ca53c61a/op_eyedropper  doesn't show an eyedropper  cursor, but works the same.