# How to draw Object selection with eyedropper layout using Python script

Tags: python, scripting

I wanted to draw this Object selector layout using Python Script
and Retrive the Selected Object Also Apply the Modifier to Selected Object

[image: Screenshot]

**I have Tried this from the another question asking for same thing
but that is not working**

```
import bpy



class Test_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Prop Panels"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "output"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        string_property = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(scene, "string_property", context.scene, "objects")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Test_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Tests_PT_layout_panel)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Enable developer tools in user preferences.  Right click on UI element and choose view source to open the python source of the UI in the text editor.

Comment: I am Not able to See or Understand Much in Source code col.label(text="Object:")
col.prop("md, object", text="") I have seen These two Lines about this thing in source code but not understood How to add that Out of Modifier

Comment: I'd like to remind you that StackExchange is a Q&A site that values questions that show that an effort has been made to solve the issue before posting. This is explained in *Search and research* ["How to ask a good question"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Related question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper

Comment: @Robert Gutzkow Thats What I wanted thank you for Posting Link to that Question Now Let me Try it

Comment: Tested the code of the dupe, I don't have any trouble. Where your "string_property" is defined?

Comment: Ok I edited this question and now string_property = PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Object) but still it do not create that type of object selector layout

Comment: Either use `col.prop_search(scene, "string_property", context.scene, "objects")
`  or   `col.prop(scene, "pointer_property")` (note the difference, coding is about attention to detail)  Btw define your pointer property in the register method. The draw method is for drawing UI.

Comment: You forgot to "register" your property to any *bpy type* like the actual *scene*. Add `bpy.types.Scene.string_property = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)` to `register()` and `col.prop(scene, "string_property")` to your `draw()` method @Rakeshchoudhary

Comment: More about Add-on development here: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)

Comment: sorry to be silly can anyone  answer me somewhat descriptively so i could understand

Comment: Added answer to dupe. Please take some time to evaluate the changes between script above and script there.  To reiterate, coding is attention to detail.