# How to pick an object before operator execution? (object picker/pointer ux?)

Tags: python, scripting, operator, interface

I have an operator that needs an object in order to work,
but here's the trick, it is **required** to use some sort of picker GUI in order to select the object first before execution() *(instead of using the more traditional bpy.context.selection or active)*

It is for creating a paint bucket tool or something similar

Note that blender does have such "pick before execute" behavior by default, for example you can use

```
def invoke(self, context, event):
    context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

to select a filepath before execution, well I want to do exactly the same thing but with a `bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)` instead of a filepath

unfortunately I didn't find any function similar to `fileselect_add()`, I was hoping for something like `objectselect_add()` sadfly it does not exists, does he?

so now I'm stuck as I don't have any picker method at my disposal

I suppose I need to go modal?
i don't have any modal experience, is there a similar project I can take a look at?

Comment: Linked question
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213782/object-picker-modal-operator

Answer (score 4):

**Update method on pointer property**

[image]

Not sure if this is a bit of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

In as much as agree that invoking the filebrowser is a way to select the filepath before executing the operator  it is generally displaying other options (often for import export) while it runs modally.

To simply select a filepath before running could achieve same with

```
def foo(self, context):
    bpy.ops.export_scene.foo(filepath=self.filepath)

Foo.filepath = StringProperty(subtype='FILE_PATH`, update=foo)
```

So similarly, can "do your thang" when the object is selected via the eyedropper.

[Object selection box with eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper)

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty

def poll(self, obj):
    return obj.type == 'MESH'

def update(self, context):
    # self is scene (or self.id_data if in prop group)
    ob = self.prop
    if ob is not None:
        print(f"Run operator or do something to {ob.name}")
        self.prop = None # reset?
    
class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Prop Panels"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(scene, "prop")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.prop = PointerProperty(
            type=bpy.types.Object,
            poll=poll,
            update=update)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*Note: have reset the pointer to none after each pick for way of example. Will prompt the "No value set warning in UI.*