# Object Picker Modal Operator?

Tags: python, scripting, operator, interface

I saw [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213735/how-to-pick-an-object-before-operator-execution-object-picker-pointer-ux) this morning and i'm also quite interested in a Picker modal operator, so I did tinker a bit and achieve a somewhat beginning of a working code but I encountered some problems along the way.

The code is functional in 3Dview, as you can see it will print objects detected under the cursor, the problem is that **it needs to work from any areas**! so we need some context override action here

(Note that, as final touch, we could draw a little icon on screen with the name of the object picked at cursor location. Not sure if this is possible cross area ? i believe custom drawing are only allowed within the 3D view correct?)

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils

# rework of this 
# https://devtalk.blender.org/t/pick-material-under-mouse-cursor/6978/4


#We need the picker to work cross area, unfortunately blender don't like that very much
#So we need to override the context, 
#the function below will try to find 3D view and update the given context.copy()

def find_3d_context(context_copy):
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    break 
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    region_data = space.region_3d
                    break
    print(area, region, region_data)
    context_copy.update(
        area=area,
        region=region,
        region_data=region_data,
        )
    return 
    

def find_object(context, event):
    
    # get the context arguments
    scene     = bpy.context.scene
    region    = bpy.context.region
    rv3d      = bpy.context.region_data
    coord     = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
    scene     = bpy.context.scene 
    viewlayer = bpy.context.view_layer
     
    #this is the tricky part, region will not be found if we are not running this operator from a 3DVIEW
    if rv3d is None: print("region_data not found") ; return 

    # get the ray from the viewport and mouse
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    ray_origin  = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    ray_target  = ray_origin + (view_vector *-10)
    ray_goal    = ray_origin + (view_vector *1000)

    Rresult, Rlocation, Rnormal, Rindex, Robject, Rmatrix = scene.ray_cast(viewlayer.depsgraph, ray_target, ray_goal)
    
    if Robject is not None:
        print("Found an object ! : ",Robject)
    return Robject



class ObjectPicker(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.test"
    bl_label = "Picker test"

    def modal(self, context, event):
    
        #should work from any area, so we need to find correct context
        context = context.copy()
        find_3d_context(context)
        
        object = find_object(context, event)
        
        if (event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE'):
            print("Execute Something With Object")
            print("Done")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC','RET'}:
            print("Done")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectPicker)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectPicker)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```