# Is there anyway to change the property input background color to red?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers, properties

I'm creating an Add-on where you have to select any object type to start using it. but I would like to know if is there any way to display a red property input if no object is selected or exists.

[image]

- This image is an screenshot of driver editor pop-up

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Yes*. Just set [`Layout.alert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=alert#bpy.types.UILayout.alert) property to `True` in case there is no object selected:

[image]

Demo based on @batFINGERs answer to [Object selection box with eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159155/31447).

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Prop Panels"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        if not scene.prop:
            col.alert = True
        else:
            col.alert = False
            
        col.prop(scene, "prop")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.prop = PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```