# Creating drop down lists for the objects in collections

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Appologies firstly, I'm very new to python and this site.

I have a small code that I am trying to create, to add an option on my panel addon.

The code is to select all collections in Blender and generate a Enum list, and then to populate a second Enum list with the objects within, the second list changing with the input from the first.

I plan to use the code once final to make the selection in the second menu active and show it in viewport, and to hide everything else.

So far, I have the following, but I'm pretty sure that this code will end up crashing blender as I'm pretty sure it re-writes the enum array with each redraw.

```
import os
import bpy
from bpy.types import (Panel, Operator)


class OBJECT_PT_Test(Panel):

    bl_label = "Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Example"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(context.scene, "test_cat", text="")
        
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(context.scene, "test_obj", text="")

def test_cat(self, context):

    Enum_items = []
    
    for collection in bpy.data.collections:
        item = (collection.name, collection.name, "")
        Enum_items.append(item)   
    return Enum_items
    #print (Enum_items) 
    
def test_obj(self, context):
    
    obj_items = []
    
    for obj in bpy.data.collections[bpy.context.scene.test_cat].objects:
        obj_item = (obj.name, obj.name, "")
        obj_items.append(obj_item)   
    return obj_items
    #print (obj_item)  
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_Test) 
    bpy.types.Scene.test_cat = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name= "Category Name", description= "Category Desc", items=test_cat)
    bpy.types.Scene.test_obj = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name= "Object Name", description= "Object Desc", items=test_obj)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.test_cat
    del bpy.types.Scene.test_obj
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_Test)
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and taken on board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even this approach is *not that beginner-friendly*  and there are a few concepts involved, I'd suggest use a [`PointerProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointer#bpy.props.PointerProperty) for each selection instead. In case there are *many collections and objects* in the scene *each enum gets crowded quickly* and makes it difficult for the user to choose from these rather *long lists*.

[image]

Demo on a [`PointerProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointer#bpy.props.PointerProperty) for collections as well as a [`PointerProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointer#bpy.props.PointerProperty) for the objects of the selected collection using its provided `poll` callback function:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


def filter_callback(self, object):
    return object.name in self.my_collection.objects.keys()

class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(scene, "my_collection")
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.enabled = True if scene.my_collection else False
        col.prop(scene, "my_collection_objects")


def register():

    bpy.types.Scene.my_collection = PointerProperty(
        name="Collection",
        type=bpy.types.Collection)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_collection_objects = PointerProperty(
        name="Object",
        type=bpy.types.Object,
        poll=filter_callback)
        
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_collection
    del bpy.types.Collection.my_collection_objects
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

As [@batFINGER mentioned in the comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234199/creating-drop-down-lists-for-the-objects-in-collections/234251?noredirect=1#comment396843_234251), you can also register a custom pointer to each [`collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection) type which allows to get the object reference via *associated collection*:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


def filter_callback(self, object):
    return self in object.users_collection

class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(scene, "my_collection")
        
        if scene.my_collection:
            col.prop(scene.my_collection, "my_active_object")


def register():
    
    bpy.types.Scene.my_collection = PointerProperty(
        name="Collection",
        type=bpy.types.Collection)
    bpy.types.Collection.my_active_object = PointerProperty(
        name="Object",
        type=bpy.types.Object,
        poll=filter_callback)
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_collection
    del bpy.types.Collection.my_active_object
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

**Related**

- [Limit "prop_search" to Specific Types of Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75185/limit-prop-search-to-specific-types-of-objects)
- [Object selection box with eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper)
- [Is there anyway to change the property input background color to red?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233742/is-there-anyway-to-change-the-property-input-background-color-to-red)
- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)

Comment: Suggest a minor change to `bpy.types.Collection.active_object = PointerProperty(type=Object)` in which case can set "object of interest in collection" for each.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER. Disadvantage is that `data` argument of `Layout.prop()` call cannot be `None` so an additional additional check is needed... However, it feels closely associated with the collection, beautiful.

Comment: NP.  Would consider using and polling on  `context.collection`  Do you know of a template ID to set the context collection|? _eg_ can `C.scene.my_collection = C.scene.collection`  in the console to set collection of interest (btw Watson IMO never use "my_" like in Mycroft or Mycrosoft lol) to the scene collection. The other question is how to add base collections as as an option to the selection.

Comment: "Can not edit built-in name" lol. Need to investigate @batFINGER

Comment: one more thing... perhaps  poll for latter could be  `return self in object.users_collection`

Comment: Interesting catch, no idea how to add the master collection @batFINGER

Comment: Many Thanks @brockmann and batFINGER, appreciate the time you have both taken to show me the correct way to approach this.

Comment: No problem, glad it helps @KevThomas