# F-Curve Selection UI

Tags: python, scripting, properties, data-blocks

I'm seeking to create a UI property that lets the user choose an an F-Curve channel.

I tried the [prop_search](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_search) method using this question's code as an example ([Object selection box with eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper)), but got an error because the PointerProperty will only register with an Object, not an F-Curve.

Can anyone advise me on how to create a user interface for selecting animation F-Curve channels? Thank you!

Comment: The error you are getting is because Object is a subclass of ID, but FCurve is not, and you can only add properties to "[to any subclass of an ID, Bone and PoseBone](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html)"

Comment: @MartyFouts, thank you for the reply. Do you have any advice on how to create a UI for selecting an F-Curve?

Comment: I don't at the moment; sorry.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks for the reply.