# How to create a system to dynamically create pointer properties?

Tags: properties, dynamic

Currently in my script I am using the Pointer Property method from [Object selection box with eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper) to allow a user to select objects for which operators in my panel will run upon. Instead of just having one or a few, I'd like the user to be able to click a +/- in order to add/remove pointer property slots, that way if they can add more if they like and aren't limited to a certain amount. I have managed something like this with UI Lists but unsure how to do it with pointers/object selections. All help is highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello ! This sounds like it would be a good match for [CollectionProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.CollectionProperty)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain a bit more how a collection property is used for this? I have used them some but not seeing how. I need the object selection eyedropper to remain next to each new field created and have add/remove buttons so the user can remove them/add them as they wish. I tried creating a for loop that would duplicate the pointer properties based on how many objects are selected but the panel can only display the prop by it's indentifier which I am not sure how to make that change based on the name or index of the object.