# selecting in python: ask to pick an object?

Tags: python, scripting, selection-tools

How do I create a picking session in python?
Say I have a script that does some operations, but its want the user to pick first a source object and then a target? How do I invoke the picking?
My guess is bpy.ops.view3d.select(), but I get a context error all the time...
What is the secret?

Comment: object picking is not available in python yet

Comment: is that what you mean http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30487/object-selection-box-with-eyedropper

Comment: exactly! thanks. guess I'll have to select the object before running the script :/

Comment: you don't have to select before you can use this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/object-selection-box-in-addon