How to join operators of a Panel?
I run bpy.ops.script.reload() and each reloaded file adds a new directory to sys.path.
In less than 10 reloads len(sys.path) > 100 with duplicate directories. I try sys.path = list(set(sys.path)) but it doesn't delete duplicates.
Is there a possibility to write between commands so as not to define two operators/buttons?
class ReloadModules(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "reload.reload"
    bl_label = "Reload All Addons"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.script.reload()
        #write?
        sys.path = list(set(sys.path))
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CleanModules(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "reload.clean"
    bl_label = "Clean Addons"

    def execute(self, context):
        sys.path = list(set(sys.path))
        return {'FINISHED'}


Operator has blender properties can use, for example:   layout.operator("reload.reload").clean = True

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clean'

You need to define the properties yourself:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17751/how-display-and-use-operator-properties-in-a-python-blender-ui-panel
