# What is the difference between bpy.props.CollectionProperty and bpy.props.PointerProperty?

Tags: python, properties

I noticed that `bpy.props.CollectionProperty` and `bpy.props.PointerProperty` can both be used to collect custom properties (as is shown here: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.props.html).

There are also other examples on the internet, but I still can't figure out the difference between these two properties.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/is-it-possible-to-use-bpy-props-pointerproperty-to-store-a-pointer-to-an-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A collection is an array of a set of properties. Every element in the array has the same properties (with individual values).

A pointer property is used to organize properties. The sub-attribute the pointer property is stored at will hold a set of properties. It is not an array of properties however.

```
Scene.collection
  Scene.collection.add()
  Scene.collection.remove()
  Scene.collection ...()
  Scene.collection[0]
    Scene.collection[0].name # Foo
    Scene.collection[0].val # 123
  Scene.collection[1]
    Scene.collection[1].name # Bar
    Scene.collection[1].val # 234
  Scene.collection[...]
    Scene.collection[...].name # Baz
    Scene.collection[...].val # 345

Scene.pointer
  Scene.pointer.name # Foo
  Scene.pointer.val # 123
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can use collections for UI-Lists (as used for vertex-groups, UV-layers... etc)

Comment: Where can I find all the methods applicable for a collection, like `add()` and `remove()` and their documentation? Thank you for you answers!

Comment: They are unfortunately not documented, you'll need to use `dir(...)` on an actual collection or use auto-complete of the Python Console. There are actually just two more important methods however, `clear()` and `move()`.