# Reference an object or data from a Python-defined property

Tags: python, interface, properties

Many built-in properties, such as Object.parent, reference scene data. In the UI, they are represented with pretty menu widgets and in certain cases also with a picker tool:

[image: Object Parent]
[image: Scene Properties]

Is it possible to create these 'reference properties' from Python? For example, to create a custom property `Object.step_parent`.

To some extent, it can be emulated by a `props.StringProperty` -- but the real reference does not break when objects are renamed, and provides a better user experience in general.

Comment: It is not possible . See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6977/2271. There were some attempts made to add this functionality but it did not get into master.  https://developer.blender.org/T37754, https://developer.blender.org/D113