# How to have PointerProperty pointing at simple Integer Property in Python/Blender?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a *Pointer Property* in my code that would be able to reference an Integer Property that exists on some data block of some object.

What is the proper way of doing it? I thought it should be as simple as the code below, but it doesn't work.

I do use *PointerProperties* a lot to reference specific object types etc., but I'm not sure how to point to a simple *Int Property*. How should I do it?

Thank you so much and I apologize if this is a trivial question.

[image]

```
import bpy
    
class Example_Class(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    int_pointer: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=bpy.types.IntProperty,
        name="Int Property Pointer",
        description = "This is the pointer to Int Property that exists somewhere else",
    )    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Example_Class)    

 
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Example_Class)
 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: PointerProperty(...) expected an RNA type derived from ID or ID Property Group
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 20, in <module>
  File "\Text", line 12, in register
ValueError: bpy_struct "Example_Class" registration error: 'int_pointer' PointerProperty could not register (see previous error)
```

Comment: The [Blender 3.x documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointerProperty.html) is confusing and very vage about this because it tells you nothing about the *type*. If you check the old [2.79 documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointer#bpy.props.PointerProperty) or enter *bpy.props.PointerProperty(* in the Python console and hit the Tab key then you will see ":arg type: A subclass of :class:`bpy.types.PropertyGroup` or :class:`bpy.types.ID`." - Basically the same as what the error message tells you.

Comment: [IntProperty(Property)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.IntProperty.html) has the base classes "bpy_struct" and "Property". That's the reason why it does not work. So you probably need to encapsulate it in another PropertyGroup. -- Related question and an answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6977/107598

Comment: Ahh!!! Got it! Thank you so much!!!