# Color as Custom Property?

Tags: python, properties

With objects, there you can add Custom Properties to an object, though it only seems to let you specify numeric values.

Is there any way that I can add a color value as a custom property, such as through Blender's python API?

**EDIT:** To clarify what I am doing: I am making a set of character models for use in a web comic I am making.  The character models will be "generic" ones for ordinary characters (ie: bystanders, pedestrians, etc.).  What I want to do is put some color field properties onto the armature (which is the parent of all the model pieces and clothing), and then use drivers in the model pieces so that they can pull the color data for the clothing, eyes, and skin.

I wish to use this method because I want to use models in a linked fashion, where I import one or more generic models and set the colors in the scene they are used in after importing, so that I don't fill up my hard drive (or my cloud drive) with dozens of .blend files for every color variation I use.

**EDIT 2:** To clarify further, I wish for a solution that can be applied on a per-model basis, rather than needing to create an addon that adds the same set of properties to all models.

Comment: This should help: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties

Comment: Does it need to appear in the Custom Properties panel? I would use a FloatVectorProperty() instead, which wouldn't show in tha panel, but can be added to any panel with a custom draw function. It would give you a color field, click to open color picker.

Comment: CoDEmanX: Yes, that's pretty much what I want.  How do I set that up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is condensed heavily edited sample add-on an artist requested t use blender as the middleman to mass convert vertex colors data from custom data source, the latter being removed as its not related to the question.

The color value was selected using FloatVectorProperty, specifically with subtype COLOR. This also has the advantage that if exposed through the UI is visualised by the nice UI Color wheel/hex-widget.

The code is split into properties.py and ui.py as this is done for ease of maintainance and separation of concerns, ie storage and display. You can store the custom property anywhere you want I choose object as per the question, the same applies for where the ui appears.

You can also combine it into one script, just need to change registration from module to class and supply each class name.

I generally use a properties group when working with multiple properties, but you can just define a single custom property to attach.
`properties.py`

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, StringProperty, PointerProperty

class ObjectProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):

        bpy.types.Object.custom = PointerProperty(
            name="Custom properties",
            description="Custom Properties for Objects",
            type=cls,
            )

        #Add in the properties you want      
        cls.hexwidget = FloatVectorProperty(name="Hex Value", 
                                        subtype='COLOR', 
                                        default=[0.0,0.0,0.0])

        cls.test_string = StringProperty(name="Test String",
                                        default="I am a string")

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Object.custom

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectProperties)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectProperties)
```

This module has specific registration handling as we prefer to get rid of custom info if the addon is not install, design decision.

Here is the UI which will display the value stored in the defined property
`ui.py`

```
import bpy

class UtilityPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Utilites Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_utilities"

    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout       

        box = layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.custom, "hexwidget")
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.custom, "test_string")
```

`__init__.py` for completeness

```
#--- ### Header
bl_info = {
    "name": "Custom Property: Color",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
import bpy.props

from <folder_name> import ui, properties

def register():
    properties.register()
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    properties.unregister()
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

When enabled the add-on adds a custom propertygroup to each Object, which can be altered or expanded as you need.

[image: Custom Panel Object Tab]

Comment: Okay, going to try this out.  Will ask if I have any trouble.

Comment: Okay, I have all three scripts copied into the text editor and registered.  How do I hook them up to an object, though?

Comment: This is the bare bones of an addon. Create a new folder in your addon directory and enable the new add-on.

Comment: Okay, and after that, how do I use it?  Also, I am going to edit the original question to put my use case down so that it fits into the context.

Comment: You need to edit the <folder_name> of __init__ to whatever you called the folder you created. Some slight corrections, works and displays in the Properties -> Object tab. See screenshot

Comment: Okay, it appears to be working now.  One last question: what do I set bl_context to if I want it to appear in the toolbox instead of the object tab?

Comment: Normally I would suggest API documentation but in this case all you get it is "The context in which the panel belongs to. (TODO: explain the possible combinations bl_context/bl_region_type/bl_space_type)". Next solution for finding out stuff is open the tab in question; Left click -> Edit Source find the bl_context.

As for the expanded version of question it might be best to start a new question, referring back tho this as the basis as its turning into a tutorial at this stage.

Comment: I think I'll just revise my original question.  Now that I've tried this solution, it doesn't really fit with what I want, since I would have the same set of properties for all of my models, whereas I would want to add them as-needed to specific models.

Comment: I wound up utilizing this solution, or rather, a heavily-modified version.  I modded it to all go into a single script, and will be embedding that script as-needed into the .blend files.  Though, I may adapt it further to make it more dynamic (ie: using a list value in Custom Properties to define the colors needed)

Comment: Well this is only to show you how to create a single custom property, you can expand as needed. You can also do the other part where you could tie the an update function for the values into the material color or via drivers.

Comment: You want to add `min=0.0` and `max=1.0` to the `FloatVectorProperty` or the color picker will spazz out trying to pick colors. Also, setting `size` to 4 allows choosing alpha values.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is a recent feature (tested on blender 3.1) or not (otherwise I don't see why nobody mentioned it before), but you can add a color property without using any sort of python, with or without alpha by simply using the type `Float Array`, set dimension to 3 (4 if you want alpha), and the Subtype should be `Linear Color` or `Gamma Corrected Colors`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is actually the correct answer to the original question. Thank you! That Subtype field only shows up when using 'Float Array'-- totally eluded me. I wish it was higher up in the list of parameters.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether this would be the intended way, but at least it works:

You could add a string representation of other datatypes than integer from the *edit dialog*, there you could paste a color value <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> copied from e.g. material settings, this would add a list with 4 floats.

[image]

To access your custom properties attached to your object e.g.

```
o=bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
c = Color( o["customColor"][:3] )
print( c )
>>> <Color (r=0.8000, g=0.2236, b=0.2440)>
```

To set a color programmatically:

```
c = Color((1,2,3))
o["customColor"]=c

c2=o["customColor"]
print(c2)
>>> <bpy id property array [3]>

print(Color(c2))
>>> <Color (r=1.0000, g=2.0000, b=3.0000)>
```

See also:

- [Assign datablock to custom property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/assign-datablock-to-custom-property)
- [Properties, ID-Properties and their differences](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties)

Answer (score 4):

Just want do add:

Similar to python [properties](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), the properties from [`bpy.props`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.props.html) basically provide setter/getter methods for custom properties which actually are items of an ID dictionary.

Creating such a property

```
bpy.types.Object.test = bpy.props.IntProperty()
```

has no effect on an object until you assign a value to its `test` attribute

```
obj.test = 4
#calls the default setter if not specified which sets the custom property
obj["test"] = 4
```

The getter method returns the default value if nothing has been set for this attribute

```
obj.test
#calls the default setter if not specified which either returns the custom property,
#if it exists, or the default value
if "test" in obj:
    return obj["test"]
else:
    return default_value
```

Custom properties will be saved to the .blend file.

Correct me if i am wrong.

### In this case:

```
#addon bl_info to be inserted here - see Templates -> Addon Add Object
import bpy

def hndl_draw(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()
    #if "myColor" in context.object.data:
    row.prop(context.object.data, "myColor")

def register():   
    bpy.types.Armature.myColor = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
                                     name = "myColor",
                                     subtype = "COLOR",
                                     size = 4,
                                     min = 0.0,
                                     max = 1.0,
                                     default = (0.75,0.0,0.8,1.0)
                                     )
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_display.append(hndl_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_display.remove(hndl_draw)
    del bpy.types.Armature.myColor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

For all armatures the specified default color will be displayed in *Properties Area* -> *Armature* -> *Display*
[image: ColorPicker]

If you don't change the color no data will be added to the armature.

You can hide this color picker for objects without the custom property `"myColor"` by uncommenting the if-line. However you will have to set `obj.data["myColor"] = (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)` manually then (via console, script or UI).

Comment: How would I apply this to a specific object?

Comment: You can simply assign a custom property. `obj["myColor"] = (100, 255, 0)`. If you create a `bpy.props.IntVectorProperty` the end result will be the same when saved to the .blend file.

Comment: My problem is I'm trying to get it to show up with a color picker.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Tried that, and it appears to work.  However, it appears that if the code is run more than once, the MyColor fields get added multiple times.

Comment: Yes. Each time you are appending a new draw handler. `bpy.types.DATA_PT_display.remove(hndl_draw)` will remove it.