# Is there a list of the different ui options I can use when making an add on?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I’m making an addon and was wondering if there’s a list of ui properties. I couldnt find any in the documentation. Are the only available ones float, int and str?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much (Int, Float, String and Bool). Are you making a menu or are you just looking for ways to store data in-between operator runs?

Comment: I guess I kinda phrased the question poorly. I understand that those are the possible outputs. I'm referring to possible ui elements to use in the menu. For example could I put a color ramp in my add on menu?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/color-as-custom-property