# Adding a color field in the addon Panel

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, color, panel

I wanted to add a color field to my Blender addon panel, with which I can adjust the color input of a Principled Volume node. But i´m struggling, how I can insert such a color field there and synchronize it with the color field of the Principled Volume. Does anybody know how to do that? I would appreciate every help!

Comment: use [FloatVectorProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:

```
import bpy

def hndl_draw(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()

    row.prop(context.object.data, "myColor")
    
def get_color(self):
    return bpy.data.materials["Material.001"].node_tree.nodes["Principled Volume"].inputs[0].default_value
    
def set_color(self, value):
    bpy.data.materials["Material.001"].node_tree.nodes["Principled Volume"].inputs[0].default_value = value
    return 

def register():   
    bpy.types.Armature.myColor = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
                                     get=get_color,
                                     set=set_color,
                                     name = "myColor",
                                     subtype = "COLOR",
                                     size = 4,
                                     min = 0.0,
                                     max = 1.0,
                                     default = (0.75,0.0,0.8,1.0)
                                     )
                                     
                                     
                                     
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_display.append(hndl_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_display.remove(hndl_draw)
    del bpy.types.Armature.myColor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note1: i used the solution from here: [Color as Custom Property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/color-as-custom-property)

Note2: i changed it a bit

Note3: you need a material called "Material.001" with a principled volume in it with exact the name i used, and an armature

result:

[image]

hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks Chris, i came to a quite similar solution yesterday and it works!